# How Dir() works in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, file

In my current VBA code I generate a variable called myFileName and would like to use it as a parameter when I am checking if the file exists but I get an error message "Runtime error 52, bad file name or number" in the line I use the Dir command.

Interestingly if I type the the filepath to the Dir command manually instead of using the myFileName variable then it works without an issue. (no typo, I can use the myFileName in reading or writing the file, it only drops an error for the Dir command)

Any ideas how can I make the Dir(myFileName) working?

```
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    myFileName = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Application Data\myFile.txt"

    If Dir(myFileName) = "" Then
        Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(myFileName, True)
        a.Write ("0")
        a.Close
    End If
```

Comment: is `myFileName` declared as a string?

Comment: Try using the .fileexists in the FSO as you've got one to create the text file/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\Application Data` is not a folder but a shortcut. Use `LOCALAPPDATA` or `APPDATA` instead:

```
myFileName = Environ("LOCALAPPDATA") & "\myFile.txt"
myFileName = Environ("APPDATA") & "\myFile.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

your issue is:

```
myFileName = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Application Data\myFile.txt"
```

it should be

```
myFileName = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Application Data" & "\" & "myFile" & ".txt"
```

This is a common question and really worth acknowledging that you have to insert the last forward slash like this. IDK why vba reads like this, but this is the work around

I just ran this with no issue and the file created.

```
Private Sub createafile()
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    myFileName = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop" & "\" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") & ".xlsm"

    If Dir(myFileName) = "" Then
        Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(myFileName, True)
        a.Write ("0")
        a.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have never had to insert the last backslash like this. Can you provide a link to an example?

Comment: Changing to what you have suggested makes the Dir(myFileName) returning an empty string, even if the file exists and then I get a "Run time error 76, path not found" error message for the CreteTextFile line

Comment: i also edited my original comment and added an extra ampersand

Comment: @lturner I have answered this question several times for people and it seemed to have been the issue. I was just under the general understanding that you needed to do this. I have never been abel to get a DIR() funciton to work without doing so.